# I need to configure CAN filters in such a way that only ID 0x80 and IDs between 0x200 and 0x300 passes all others are not allowed to be passed

Tags: c, filtering, stm32, can-bus

I tried in this way but the problem is only 200-300 can pass but 80h is not passed. if I use if-else then only 80h is passed not 200-300h. So, the problem is I can pass either 80h or 200h-300h. Not both 80h and 200-300h.

```cpp
#define Filter_ID1  0x80

#define Filter_ID2  0x200


#if Filter_ID1

sFilterConfig.FilterMode = CAN_FILTERMODE_IDMASK;

sFilterConfig.FilterScale = CAN_FILTERSCALE_32BIT;

sFilterConfig.FilterBank = 0;

sFilterConfig.FilterIdHigh=0x80<<5;

sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdHigh=0xff<<5;

sFilterConfig.FilterIdLow = 0x0000;

sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdLow = 0x0000;

sFilterConfig.FilterFIFOAssignment = CAN_RX_FIFO0;

sFilterConfig.FilterActivation = ENABLE;

#endif


#if Filter_ID2

sFilterConfig.FilterMode = CAN_FILTERMODE_IDMASK;

sFilterConfig.FilterScale = CAN_FILTERSCALE_32BIT;

sFilterConfig.FilterBank = 1;

sFilterConfig.FilterIdHigh=0x200<<5;

sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdHigh=0x300<<5;

sFilterConfig.FilterIdLow = 0x0000;

sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdLow = 0x0000;

sFilterConfig.FilterFIFOAssignment = CAN_RX_FIFO0;

sFilterConfig.FilterActivation = ENABLE;

#endif
```

Comment: You seem to mix up the mask and the values. If anything between 0x200 and 0x300 is allowed, then you can't look at that part of the identifier at all. Generally, this acceptance mask crap was so tiresome to get right that it usually caused more harm than good... I'd strongly recommend to use a modern CAN controller with mailboxes instead. Although that might rule out STM32, I guess.

Comment: @Lundin what did you lead to this conclusion? https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/training/technical/product_training/group0/8b/ec/0c/16/9d/fa/49/59/STM32G4-Peripheral-Flexible_Datarate_Controller_Area_Network_FDCAN/files/STM32G4-Peripheral-Flexible_Datarate_Controller_Area_Network_FDCAN.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.STM32G4-Peripheral-Flexible_Datarate_Controller_Area_Network_FDCAN.pdf

Comment: @0___________ So they've finally replaced "bxCAN"? About time. Ironically, other ST parts have had mailboxes for ages, such as SPC56. Though that one was mostly developed by Freescale I think...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure two filter banks:

For [0x200, 0x300) range (0x300 excluded), you need **Identifier Mask** mode. In this case:

- Mask (FxR2) = 0x300 (check bits 8 & 9, ignore others)
- ID (FxR1) = 0x200 (Bits 8 & 9 needs to be 0b10)

For 0x80, you need **Identifier List** mode. For 32-bit list, a filter bank contains 2 items. In order to accept only 0x80, you need to fill them with the same value (0x80 twice)

- ID (FxR1) = 0x80
- ID (FxR2) = 0x80

More than one filter bank can be active at the same time.

`FiRx` is the naming convention used by the reference manual, where *i = 0..27* (filter bank number) and *x = 1,2* (register number). I don't know how the library you're using calls them.

Of course, the values I mentioned are just the logical values. You need to shift/modify them to fit your HW registers. I'm not sure left shifting by 5 is correct. It seems `<< 3` is the correct value to me. See **Filter bank scale configuration - register organization** figure in your reference manual

Comment: i understand your point and its completely right in accordence with the basics. But now i have found that i have problem to impliment multiple filter bank. Can you give me an example code where multiple filter banks are being used?

Comment: I think no additional effort is needed, just activate them both at the same time. But I still think there can be errors in your config register assignments. Their names are somewhat confusing and they don't directly match the HW register names. You need to refer to the library documentation.

Comment: thanks for your help. It works finally. i used two filter banks. the configuration variable must be two for two banks. sFilterConfig1 and sFilterConfig2. i used only one variable in my program so at a time one was used.